# Proof of the Kunita-Watanabe Identity

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

We discussed the following version of the Kunita-Watanabe identity in a recent lecture on stochastic analysis, and I don't quite understand how the proof works.

Let $X, Y$ be semimartingales and $H$ an $X$- and $\langle X, Y \rangle$-integrable process. Then one has:

\begin{equation}
\langle H \cdot X, Y \rangle = H \cdot \langle X, Y \rangle.
\end{equation}

In order to prove this, it suffices to consider local martingales for $X$ and $Y$ (this I understand). We then showed that

$$ ((H \cdot X)_t Y_t - (H \cdot \langle X,Y \rangle )_t)_{t \geq 0} $$

is a martingale. This is supposed to imply the desired result, since the right side of the equation above is a process of locally bounded variation started in 0.

My problem is that I don't understand why this implies the result. Why is this enough?

Comment: As far as I remember: It is enough because for a semimartingale $Z=M+A$ the quadratic variation $\langle Z\rangle$ is the unique, increasing, predictable process such that $M^2-\langle Z\rangle$ is a (local) martingale. See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203107/quadratic-variation-and-predictable-quadratic-variation-for-martingales).

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, that would be why, thank you! (I checked and this is also true for the covariation, in which case $\langle X,Y \rangle$ is the unique process $Z$ so that $XY - Z$ is a (local) martingale.)

Comment: @LarsSK21 Minor correction, but $\langle X,Y \rangle$ is the unique process *of finite variation* $Z$ such that $XY-Z$ is a (local) martingale.  Easy to forget that finite variation part and mistake another semi-martingale for $\langle X,Y \rangle$.